# 3d model crash in maya and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, mesh, maya

First, I apologize because my English is not good
I have several 3D models. When I enter Maya or Blender, there are holes in the middle of the model. It is shown in the same way in Unity. It doesn't hurt, the model doesn't support shadows or anything else, and it takes the fancy mode, that's why I have to use other normal shaders, which are like this, and I make them in Maya from the normal menu, but again when outputting in Unity They are shown in this way, now what is the solution, how can I fix this crash mode in Maya or Blender?

https://s30.picofile.com/file/8471383684/photo.jpg